# In Highcharts, my dataLabels disappear when re-enabling the rightmost element of my chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using react-highcharts to draw a relatively simple column chart for some work data. The bosses wanted it set up so that hiding an item on the legend will adjust the scale, even if the element is in the middle of the chart. I followed [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2e942js4/3/) fiddle from the highcharts forum to make my data vanish and reappear. Great, everything works! But I have a bug I can't pin down in my code.

Whenever I remove and then return the rightmost visible element, the second-from-the-right element loses its data label. [image: Returned Chart with no data Label]

I'm reasonably certain that the issue lies in my HighCharts options object. Here it is below:

```
 const highChartsOptionsObject= {
chart: {
  type: "column",
  style: {
    fontFamily: "helvetica",
  },
  height: 300,
},
title: {
  text: null,
},
xAxis: {
  allowDecimals: true,
  type: "category",
  crosshair: true,
},
yAxis: {
  min: 0,
  title: {
    text: getLabel(),
  },
  labels: {
    formatter: getLabelString()
    },
  },
},
credits: {
  enabled: false,
},
legend: {
  enabled: true,
},
tooltip: {
  formatter: function () {
    return `
      <b>${this.point.name}</b><br />
      ${
        getTooltip();
      }
    `;
  },
},
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    stacking: "normal",
    pointPadding: 0.3,
    borderWidth: 0,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      crop: false,
      overflow: "none",
      formatter: function () {
        const labelString = "hard coded test";
        return labelString;
      },
    },
  },
  series: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function () {
        if (this.visible) {
          this.setData([], false);
        } else {
          let elementData = getSeries()[this.index].data[0];
          this.setData([{ ...elementData }], false);
        }
      },
    },
  },
},
series: getSeries(),
```

};

For reference, my other highcharts options are: immutable: true and allowChartUpdate: true

Happy to provide more information if someone thinks that something else is relevant, I just need to sanitize it somewhat to go on SO.

Comment: I tried to reproduced the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/m1rh9pLj/5/ but it works fine. Maybe it comes from the formatter: getLabelString() in yAxis.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with the sample data on some online editor which I could work on? If you want to do it in the React environment start from this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nwseym?file=index.js If pure JS is enough, start from this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Bastss/rwmb6dpy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some googling, and I identified my issue finally. During transitions, the data labels on the columns overlap. If you have not set allowOverlap to true for data labels, then it will default to false. Since the transition causes overlap, highcharts will set one of the datalabels to be invisible/not show up.

This can be fixed easily enough by just setting:

```
    dataLabels:{
       allowOverlap: true
        }
```